# Why doesn't autotest run my rspec tests (ruby no rails)?

Tags: ruby, rspec, autotest

I've used autotest in other project on my machine.
I'm now doing a small ruby project that uses rspec.

I can run the tests with `rspec spec` and they all run.

I've added 'autotest' to my `Gemfile` and I've `bundle`'d.
I can run `autotest` but it doesn't run my rspec tests in `spec/`

I've added empty `.rspec` and `.autotest` files.
I've tried both the `autotest` and the `autotest-standalone` gems.
I've reviewed all the info at http://ph7spot.com/musings/getting-started-with-autotest#troubleshooting_autotest_test_detection which was helpful but didn't solve my question.

Comment: If you want to share something you noticed useful, you could write blog on those...

Comment: Good idea.  I may do that.  I usually post to SO first and primarily for greatest reach to help others who may have such a problem.  I rely on SO for all the helpful infrastructure it provides.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed (and didn't have)

```
gem 'rspec'
```

in my Gemfile (and then `bundle` of course)

I hadn't realized this because with rspec on my machine from other projects and thus the ability to do `rspec spec` 'manually', I didn't realize that I needed to list the gem explicitly i.e. in the Gemfile.

I also verified that:

- I DO need the .rspec file  It's OK if it's empty but it needs to exist.
  It can be created with `touch .rspec` on *nix.
- I do NOT require a `.autotest` file.

Comment: as a general rule I think it is advisable to call `rspec` within `bundle exec rspec` to make sure your Gemfile contains the right gems.